# What's the best tool for usage reporting on a NetScreen Firewall?

Tags: firewall, logging, reporting, usage, netscreen

Anyone got a good product for Usage Reporting for a NetScreen Firewall.

I went looking for Webtrends Firewall Suite but it appears to have disappeared into the NetIQ product line up.

I am going to try out ManageEngine (I think is also AdventNet)'s Firewall Log Analyzer.

But wanted to know if anyone had any good recommendations.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: I kicked off an evaluation with ManageEngine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at NetIQ and can confirm that WebTrends Firewall Suite became NetIQ Firewall Suite back in 2001, it was subsequently sold to Marshal (marshal8e6.com) in 2006. I believe you would now be looking at Marshal8e6 Security Reporting Center.

Regards
David

Comment: Very cool - thanks for that - I had looke briefly at Marshal and will look at it again - they appear to have two products - 8e6 Professional Edition and WebMarshal - not sure which one was Security Reporting Center - I will give them a call.

Answer (score 0):

Having asked this question before, the resounding answer was to enable Counting on the interfaces of interest. However, I didn't find it very nice to look at or easy to digest.

Comment: Yeah that would show IO by bytes (similar to MRTG or PRTG graphing the bandwidth - but not the usage (FTP vs. HTTP, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The Netscreen SNMP MIB includes counters for all interfaces and policies, so you should be able to graph them using [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net) or a similar SNMP monitoring product.  (I haven't implemented policy graphs yet myself, or I would have linked to them.)